# Hippomocks: Attribute is Value not a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, mocking, hippomocks

I am new to Hippomocks and C++. I try to write an Unittest where an exception is catched. For this I have written the following test:

```
#include <ostream>
#include "../Mocks/hippomocks.h"

///////  Mocking Test Classes /////////////////////

class IBar {                         // class used inside test class
public:
    virtual ~IBar() {}
    virtual int c(std::string s, int i)      // function to be mocked
        {
            if ( s == std::string("Hallole" ))
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else
        {
            return 7;
        }
    };
};

class Foo1 {

    public:
    Foo1(){ std::cout << "hier1" << std::endl;};
    IBar *bar;
    int a()                                  // function to under (unit-)test
    {
        return this->bar->c("Hallole", 3);
    };
};

class Foo2 {

public:
    Foo2(){ std::cout << "hier2" << std::endl;};
    IBar bar;
    int a()                                  // function to under (unit-)test
    {
        return this->bar.c("Hallole", 3);
    };
};


///////  Mocking Test Classes End /////////////////////


void test(){


    ///////  Test hippomock /////////////////////

    MockRepository mocks;

    IBar *b = mocks.Mock<IBar>();
    Foo1 *g = new Foo1();

    g->bar = b;

    mocks.ExpectCall(g->bar, IBar::c).Throw(std::exception());
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW (g->a(), std::exception);

    ///////  Test hippomock end /////////////////////


}

void TestTest::test_a(){

    ///////  Test hippomock /////////////////////

    MockRepository mocks;

    IBar *b = mocks.Mock<IBar>();


    Foo2 *g = new Foo2();

    // g->bar = *b;
    memcpy(&g->bar, b, sizeof(*b));
    mocks.ExpectCall(b, IBar::c).Throw(std::exception()); 
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_THROW (g->a(), std::exception);

    ///////  Test hippomock end /////////////////////

}
```

`test()` works correctly, it's an example I found on https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/hippomocks/Tutorial_3_0.

But if I run `test_a()` no exception is thrown and I get the following:

```
uncaught exception of type HippoMocks::CallMissingException
- Function with expectation not called!
Expections set:
TestTest.cpp(97) Expectation for IBar::c(...) on the mock at 0x0x7f14dc006d50 was not satisfied.
```

I see that the difference between Foo1 and Foo2 is that in Foo1 the attribute bar is a pointer and in Foo2 it's the value. My questions are:

1. Why is there a different behavior? Or rather why is the exception not thrown, since I set  `memcpy(&g->bar, b, sizeof(*b))` for the mock-object b?
2. How can I fix it without changing the classes?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does really nobody know an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your problem on my system. looks kind of the same on my end.

My guess is, that the problem is you are hard copying the mock.

Your expectation is literally that `"b"` will be called, and in fact `g->bar` will be called.

I don't really know how it is done but i think the mock stores the call information somewhere in it self.

But I get an quite different error if I try to do it with `"&(g->bar)"`.

stacktrace points to

```
void _Adopt(const _Container_base12 *_Parent)
```